# Create a new WinRT Projection?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-runtime

I am wondering if anyone knows of any resources for, or has any experience with the creation of a WinRT language projection. I am doing some research on what it would take to create the projection for Haskell. I have found some blogs and videos on the existing projections and they mention the concept of creating new projections for other languages, but I have not been able to find much on where to start in creating one. I understand a bit of how COM works and have been getting familiar with the WinRT API as exposed to C++/CX. Thanks.

Comment: Martyn Lovell gave [a talk on exactly this topic](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2012/The-Windows-Runtime). There is a resources slide at the very end of the talk.

Comment: @RaymondChen The link is dead

Comment: @GDI512 All I had to do was type "next 2012 the windows runtime" into a search engine and [the link came back](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/lang-next-2012/windows-runtime). Search engines are cool. You should try them.

Comment: @RaymondChen Lol